# QML: How to set dynamically created component to the Loader

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am creating new QML screen using following code.

```
var newComp = Qt.createComponent(“test.qml”);
var newObject = newComp.createObject(parent, {“x”: 0, “y”: 0});
```

I wan to set this component to the loader.

I have tried to do it using `Loader.sourceComponent = newObject;`

it works but it gives me following error.

```
“Error: Cannot assign QObject* to QDeclarativeComponent*”
```

Is there any workaround for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Loader.sourceComponent has to be a Component, so

```
Loader.sourceComponent = newComp
```

should work.

But this is pretty much the same as

```
Loader {
    source: "test.qml"
}
```